# java stream How to merge same value to list

Tags: java, java-stream, grouping, array-merge

My entity is

```
private String subject;
private String unit1;  
private String unit2;  
private String unit3;  

List<entity> getList = repo.findAll();
```

"getList" show this list
my controller return this value

```
 [
        {
          "unit1": "wert",
          "unit2": "2",
          "unit3": "6",
          "subject": "grdg"
        },
        {
          "unit1": "sdfg",
          "unit2": "2",
          "unit3": "e",
          "subject": "gdsg4"
        },
        {
          "unit1": "sdfg",
          "unit2": "3",
          "unit3": "hrh",
          "subject": "g4ds"
        },
        {
          "unit1": "qwer",
          "unit2": "4",
          "unit3": "rh5",
          "subject": "g4e"
        },
        {
          "unit1": "asdf",
          "unit2": "5",
          "unit3": "erty",
          "subject": "asdf"
        },
    {
      "unit1": "zxcv",
      "unit2": "2",
      "unit3": "3",
      "subject": "asdf"
    }
  ]
```

and i want to merge same subject

```
{asdf:[{"unit1": "wert",
      "unit2": "2",
      "unit3": "6"},{ "unit1": "zxcv",
      "unit2": "2",
      "unit3": "3"}],
g4e:[{
          "unit1": "qwer",
          "unit2": "4",
          "unit3": "rh5"}]
        }
}
```

I mean i want to merge like this

```
{ subject_name:[other_data]}
```

---

```
getList.stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Subject::getSubject)).values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

that code merge is right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sufficient code to groupBy is to *not extract values* out of the grouped `Map` so as you are left with a mapping of each subject to its corresponding `List` of entities.

```
Map<String, List<Subject>> subjectMap = getList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Subject::getSubject));
```

Further, when you want to map the elements of the `List<Subject>` to another view type, you can perform a mapping operation as:

```
Map<String, List<Wrapper>> subjectMap = getList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Subject::getSubject,
                Collectors.mapping(Wrapper::extractAttributes,
                        Collectors.toList())));
```

with an additional class defined as(or you could have chosen to mutate the existing `Subject` class as well):

```
@Builder
static class Wrapper {
    private String unit1;
    private String unit2;
    private String unit3;

    public static Wrapper extractAttributes(Subject subject) {
        return Wrapper.builder().unit1(subject.getUnit1())
                .unit2(subject.getUnit2())
                .unit3(subject.getUnit3()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: how about this
 asdf: [
                {
                    "unit1":
                        [{
                            "getdata": [{
                                                  "unit2": [{ "unit2_va": [{"unit3": "aaa"},{"unit3": "ccc"}
                                        ]
                                    }]
                            }]
                        }
                        ]
                }]

Comment: @user3066285 you might just be looking for nested `groupingBy`

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
 asdf: [
                {
                    "unit1":
                        [{
                            "getdata": [{
                                "unit2": "asdff",
                                "unit3": "aaa"
                            }, {
                                "unit2": "3sfa",
                                "unit3": "ff"
                            }, {
                                "unit2":
                                    [{
                                        "unit2_va": [
                                            {"unit3": "aaa"},
                                            {"unit3": "ccc"}
                                        ]

                                    }]
                            }]
                        }
                        ]
                }]
```

is that a same way?